# Google Sheets: How to assign and add variables together for Attendance Taking/Grading

Tags: google-sheets

I have a PE teacher that wants to make her grading simple.

She has a 5 point system: 5 points for Attending on Time, Being Properly Dressed, and Participating. She wants to be able to put a letter in the cell for the apporiate score such as H=5 or (Absent) A=0, or (Tardy) T=4. Once a student has all their variables typed into the row we then want to get the sum of the variables. I am having trouble, as I am able to assign a value to a variable but when I enter that variable into the cell I see the number e.g. i type =H in the cell but 5 shows up. How can I do this so she can put letters down and get the sum afterwards?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Are all the variables being entered into the same cell, or do you have a specific column for each one? (The latter will make this much easier, but the former can be done with RegEx)

Answer (score 2):

Other thing you can do is to create a table with the values and their corresponding numbers. Then you can look up the values of the qualifications in each row, and SUM them.

In my example A1:B6 is my table of reference. And in A8 I have this formula for summing that row:

```
=SUM(INDEX(XLOOKUP(B8:8,$A$1:$A$6,$B$1:$B$6,,0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that would be to use [named ranges](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175). If you have a named cell `H` that contains `5` and a named cell `T` that contains `4`, `=H` will get `5` and `=H + T` will get `9`.

You can toggle the view between letters and through **View > Show > Formulas**.

Comment: Yes, but how can i have H show instead of 5 in the cell.

For ultimately we want to put H in the cell and then sum the cells.

Comment: Edited the answer. Consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.